# Database server is better to have SAS than SATA, also preferable RAID1?

Tags: raid, sata, sas

I want to know if it's better to hast DB server by SAS hard disk than SATA hard disk?

And it's also better to use RAID1.

I don't know much about RAID.

If the server is RAID6 default. Can I change it to RAID1? How?

Comment: A bit more info on the hardware and what applications you are using (or planning to use) would help.

Comment: You should read up on raid levels.  RAID1 is probably not what you want.  as an example.  If you have a 8 disk raid 6 array of 500G disks, you would end up with (8-2)*500G = 3000G of usable storage.  With RAID1, you'd get 500G of usable storage.

Comment: You really should read our [Canonical RAID question](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) - it has all your answers.

Comment: I heard raid5 and raid6 are all slow. Better to do raid1+0 or raid0+1 to gain speed and safety. If disks are many, better raid1+0. Reasonable?

Comment: "RAID5 and RAID6 are all slow." That's a vast oversimplification. Sometimes RAID5 is faster than RAID10, but for your case of a DB RAID10 is likely the best. And judging by your comment, you haven't read the Canonical RAID question which has LOTS of useful information in it. Please read.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if it's better to hast DB server by SAS hard disk than SATA hard disk?

Depends. I am very happy witha  system of 8 SATA discs (Velociraptor) and 2 SSD + operating system discs. Better is relative - also depends on needed speed. The window for SAS is narrow, though - need too much speed and SSD are cheaper. I use a SAS backplane, though. THe Server has now a total of 22 discs, 24 slots, the next upgrade puts it into a new case for 72 discs.

> And it's also better to use RAID1.

Better than WHAT?

> I don't know much about RAID.

Read the documentation.

> If the server is RAID6 default. Can I change it to RAID1? How?

Depends on the server. Hardware raid? Did I mention it is a decent idea to read the documentation? Software - what OS?

In general, database servers either are trivial or require someone with knowledge what he does to plane the IO layout / budget properly.